# Can you give me an example of a subgraph of a graph G that is not induced?

Tags: graph-theory

I understand what a vertex-induced subgraph is but I can't imagine a subgraph that is not induced.

Comment: Why am I being downvoted lol

Comment: It's a "feature" of this site. If people post questions where they haven't "shown their work", i.e., indicated their own thoughts on the matter, then they get downvoted. I've tried to make sense of it, but ultimately decided I had better things to do with my time on Earth.

Answer (score 4):

Graph: $A-B-C$

Non-induced subgraph: $A~~~ B-C$

Comment: Ah. I see. So you can have a subset of the vertices but you don't have to have all the edges connecting them

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge 4$, any $n$-cycle is a non-induced subgraph of $K_n$